# Move subfolders to the parent folder

Tags: windows-10, command-line, batch

I want to move subfolders out from the folders they're in, using cmd or powershell.

Structure of each subfolders should be kept. There's no any rule on how folders are named, and many folders have non-ascii letters.

The folder structure I want to change is below.

```
rootfolder        rootfolder
|-folder          |-subfolder
| |-subfolder     |-subfolder
| |-subfolder     |-subfolder
| |-subfolder ==> |-subfolder
|-folder          |-subfolder
  |-subfolder     |-subfolder
  |-subfolder     
  |-subfolder
```

I searched through stackexchange sites and couldn't get a safer or fitting one.

I found [one commandline command starting with `for /r`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48158550) and it ended up moving subfolders of every depth in the folders.
I found [one seems to be useful when both source and destination folders are set](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22092943), but I need to do this in various folders. I don't know how to put a relative path in the command, like `./` or `../`.
[This one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31144592) also introduces a command that can be used when folder names have a pattern.
There was also this [creative solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28733781) to move all nested folders in a folder, but I wonder if it will keep the structure of the nested folders. Also apparently I can't filter subfolders from direct folders lying inside the root folder in the search result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go with PowerShell:

```
$rootfolder = 'C:\Whatever'
$sourcefolders = Get-ChildItem $rootfolder -Directory
$sourcefolders |
   Get-ChildItem -Directory |
      Move-Item -Destination $rootfolder 
$sourcefolders | remove-item
```

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that you want to move only the first level of subfolders
and the solutions you already found also traverse lower levels.

The following `.bat` file will do the operation. Store it in the rootfolder
and invoke from there.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "tokens=*" %%G in ('dir /b /a:d "path\to\rootfolder"') do (
  for /f "tokens=*" %%H in ('dir /b /a:d "%%G"') do move "%%G\%%H" "path\to\rootfolder"
)
```

Comment: It works! Also adding `rmdir %%G` under line 4 made it to delete empty folders left.

Comment: So why haven't you accepted this answer, if it worked for you?

Comment: First I couldn't decide which answer to accept because both *basically* worked. The only difference was if the code deletes the empty folders after the move operation. If I could accept multiple answers I would have tried to edit your answer to include the delete command and then accepted it.